# AWS lambda cannot import name '_bcrypt'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-lambda, paramiko

I have written a simple python script which will ssh to a EC2 instance and run a script in that instance.

I use paramiko library to do ssh connect.Below is my code snippet.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    # Download private key file from secure S3 bucket
    s3_client.download_file('test','test.pem', '/tmp/test.pem')
    k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/tmp/test.pem")
    c = paramiko.SSHClient()
    c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    bastion_host = "xxx.com"
    print ("Connecting to " + bastion_host)
    c.connect(hostname=bastion_host, username="yyy", key_filename="/tmp/test.pem")
    print ("Connected to " + bastion_host)
    commands = [

        "sh /home/ec2-user/TestDeploy.sh"
    ]
    for command in commands:
        print ("Executing {}".format(command))
        stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(command)
        print (stdout.read())
        print (stderr.read())
return 'Hello from Lambda'
```

In my local setup where the python version is 3.6.2 it is working fine. But when i upload it along with all the dependent libraries in AWS lambda and run,  it gives me the below error.

```
cannot import name '_bcrypt'
```

I have verified that i have the bcrypt folder in the uploaded zip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing your local PC is not a linux PC.

You need to build your deployment package on a linux PC. Lambda underneath runs AMI images, which is based on linux.

I have documented this on my own blog [here](http://dayo.com.ng/deploying-aws-lambda-windows-pc/)

Comment: The answer to the question could just be "You need to build your deployment package on a linux PC".
Everything else I have added is so it's just more than a line.
Want me to remove the link?

Comment: The question is much about python as it is about AWS lambda. From the OPs question, he seems to be already familiar with both, he just missed a tiny, but critical detail.
The link is more of a guide for a first timer trying to deploy python code to AWS lambda.
For this question, I feel any attempt to fleshen it up will only obscure the "direct/actual" answer.

Comment: So, I was penalized and lost 2 points. Better not to have answered, yea?

Comment: So, in summary, I should not expect to make any sense out of all this.
The reason one would discover a question missing an answer on SO, spend 3 hours solving it, posting the answer back...is certainly not to get penalized.

Your over-zealousness to enforce "structure" over correctness, deciding to take action (flag) on the answer to a question you have no technical or contextual understanding about, is largely to blame.

All you had to do was ask first, act later.

Comment: Yes, that is how you could summarize it. Sorry about that. On the plus-side, it looks my edit kicked it out the [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16870834) so that is one worry less.

Comment: Let me clean-up comments then so this gets a fair chance to gather upvotes.

Comment: Thanks Dayo. I did build my package in linux with python 3.6. but still it was failing . It was working fine when i built it with 2.7 and run it on lambda 2.7.